# How to add a common view to different xib?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Im a novice in iPhone/iPad programming. My question is, how can I add a common view to two or more views (or xib file). say, for example Im planning to add a common menu to be displayed on different xib. currently Im adding the same elements (buttons) to all the xibs. is there any convenient way?

Answer (score 0):

Take your common view in `MainWindow.xib` file and also take its `IBOutlet` and property in AppDelegate file..

Connect your `IBOutlet` properly and when to use it in other view controller you should create Your appDelegate instance and then add your common view into your viewcontroller and set its frame.

Example like ...

```
[appDelegate.indicatorView setFrame:CGRectMake(107, 213, 106, 81)];
[self.view addSubview:appDelegate.indicatorView];
```

Where `appDelegate` is your instance object and by creating your view property you can access it..
indicatorView is your common view in `MainWindow.xib` file..

Comment: could you plz explain in more details ? as per I mentioned in my post, Im totally novice in iPhone/iPad programming.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using tab bar controller?

User tab bar controller and hide tab bar and add your custom menu items(buttons).See below code and try it.

```
- (void) hideTabBar
{
     for(UIView *view in tabController.view.subviews)
     {
         if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
         {
            view.hidden = YES;
            break;
         }
     }
}

- (void) addCustomTabs
{
     totalTabs = 5;
     CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 49.0);

     tabScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 460.0-rect.size.height, 320.0, rect.size.height)];
     tabScroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     tabScroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
     [tabController.view addSubview:tabScroller];

     float x = 0.0;
     for (int i = 0; i < totalTabs; i++) {
          customTabs[i] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
          customTabs[i].frame = CGRectMake(x, 0.0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
          customTabs[i].tag = i;
          [customTabs[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(selectTab:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
          [customTabs[i] setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          [tabScroller addSubview:customTabs[i]];
          x += rect.size.width;
      }

      tabScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, rect.size.height);
}

- (void) selectTab:(id)sender
{
      int tabID = [sender tag];

      for (int i = 0; i < totalTabs; i++) {
         customTabs[i].selected = NO;
      }

      customTabs[tabID].selected = YES;
      tabController.selectedIndex = tabID;

}
```

Comment: actually I want the menu to be appeared on the top. can I implement this using tab bar?